# Drupal 8: Lightning / Panelizer - can't find select box to set In Place or Standard panels

Tags: drupal, drupal-8

I am using Drupal 8 Acquia Lightning starter kit.  I created a taxonomy and applied panels to the Taxonomy term page display.  I remember at one point that I was able to access a select box that would allow me to select the Standard or In Place panel editing.  I selected Standard because I did not want the client to make any edits to the page layout.  I now need to turn on the In Place editing but I cannot find that select box anywhere.

I have tried looking in the following location:
/admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/channel/overview/display/full

This is the "Taxonomy term page" option in the "Manage Display" tab of my vocabulary.  I then click on the Edit button beside my page/panel layout.  At that point I go into the Panelizer Wizard and see 4 tabs:

- General Settings
- Contexts
- Layout
- Content

None of these tabs contain the select box to let me select Standard or In place.  Does anyone know where I can access that configuration setting?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox you're looking for is "Allow each taxonomy term to have its display customized" and it's on the Manage Display tab for your vocabulary (not inside the wizard for one of the displays). So if your vocabulary's machine name is "foo", you would find it at "/admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/foo/overview/display":

[image]

You can find a video demonstrating the relevant user story (albeit regarding nodes) here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MYFN6pET3nM&t=98s&index=6&list=PL1mMXADjTKGXRkGDyRVYorhFA-mdkx8SF

Comment: Thanks Adam but that wasn't my question.  I know how to apply panels to a display whether it is a taxonomy or node.  What I needed information on was within the Panel configuration for the term.  When setting that up originally there was a select box for In Place or Standard.  That select box had disappeared so I couldn't change it.  I had to use the Configuration Sync module and edit the YML files to use In Place rather than Standard.  Then I had to import that configuration setting.  Hope that helps anyone else w/ the issue